# Navigation Drawer twitches on close

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I try implement Navigation Drawer (Material Design) in my app. My activity contains FrameLayout with fragments. When user select item in Navigation Drawer FrameLayout reload new fragment:

```
    listViewDrawer.setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            drawerLayout.closeDrawer( listViewDrawer); // <<<-------

            toolbar.setTitle( getResources().getString( R.string.title));

            fragmentMain = new FragmentMain();

            android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                       .replace( R.id.frameLayoutMain, ApplicationTapaKiosk.getInstance().fragmentMain)
                       .commit();

        }
     }
```

When I click on item all work fine. Navigation Drawer closed not smoothly but with frozen (twitches, jerks) because fragment reload in background.

How close Navigation Drawer smoothly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to decide whether you like more:

*replacing `Fragment` in your `FrameLayout` and then closing `DrawerLayout`*

or

*closing `DrawerLayout` and then replacing your `Fragment`.*

### To implement the first approach:

just make those changes in your code:

```
listViewDrawer.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title));

        fragmentMain = new FragmentMain();

        android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                   .replace(R.id.frameLayoutMain, ApplicationTapaKiosk.getInstance().fragmentMain)
                   .commit();

        fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions(); // wait for the transaction to finish
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(listViewDrawer); // call closeDrawer(...) as a last thing
    }
 }
```

### To implement the second approach:

set some sort of flag when user clicked:

```
listViewDrawer.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        mDrawerItemClicked = true;
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(listViewDrawer); 
    }
 }
```

and set `DrawerLayout.DrawerListener` on your `DrawerLayout`, like this:

```
drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
        if (mDrawerItemClicked){
            mDrawerItemClicked = false;

            toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title));
            fragmentMain = new FragmentMain();
            android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                   .replace(R.id.frameLayoutMain, ApplicationTapaKiosk.getInstance().fragmentMain)
                   .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you sir !! Exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 3):

it takes about 200 milliseconds for the drawer to close. so you can do something like:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();

drawerLayout.closeDrawer( listViewDrawer);
mHandler.postDelayed(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run () {
                        loadFragment();
                    }
                }
                , NAVDRAWER_CLOSE_DELAY // 250...for delay
        );
```

Comment: when I use this delay Navigation Drawer close fast without froze, but my fragment not updated until delay. Fragment start reload only after 200 ms delay and this is "frozed" fragment.... Is there any solution without frozen in both Navigation Drawer and Fragments? :(

Comment: well, you can animate...fade out your current fragment, close the drawer, fade in new fragment. i don't have jirks when closing but i'm using this code because it's syncing nicely. also this code is being used by google in their `google IO` demo app